# Issues with NextJs project version upgrade from 9.0.1 to 9.0.4

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I upgraded my project version from 9.0.1 to 9.0.4 from the package.json

```
"next": "9.0.4"
```

The aim of this project upgrade is to use the built-in compression which was included in NextJs on version 9.0.4.

And i have ensured, according to NextJs document, that Head from next/document is used only inside _document, while Head from next/head is used on everywhere else.

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document"; // For _document.js use only
import Head from "next/head"; // For every other pages and _app
```

After this project version upgrade, i noticed several things

Firstly the next-head-count tag is missing. It popped out this console error when i run it on dev mode

```
index.js:1 Warning: next-head-count is missing. https://err.sh/next.js/next-head-count-missing
```

I checked this and found out that the next-head-count is rendered inside the body tag, when it was supposed to render inside the head tag.

Secondly i noticed that the link tags and title were rendered inside both head and body tags.

```
<head>
  // All the link tags rendered in here
</head>
<body>
  // next-head-count rendered in here 
  // Title tag in here
  // All the link tags rendered in here too
</body>
```

[image: Double rendering issue]

Are these normal in NextJs? I scared the next-head-count error would cost me broken SEO, functionalities and other stuffs when in live mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok after hours of debugging and googling around, finally found the root cause.

It turns out that no div is allowed inside Head tag. Any div (or React component that generates div) inside Head and it will cause that Head to be rendered inside Body. Had one GoogleTagManager component inside the Head which returns a div block. After removing that, everything went fine, and the Head rendered properly as expected.